# Migrating records from one db to mysql it is very slow with Delphi and Firedac

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac, advantage-database-server

I have to migrate several records more than 100000 from Advantage Database Local to Mysql ( local ).

I am testing with this code but its results very very slow. More than 2 hours
to migrate 120000 records.

I need some help to improve speed maybe modifying the code or some firedac properties.

The code it's very simple. I request all records from a Advantable table and do a loop for each record and insert into the mysql local db.

```
    // ADVANTAGE TABLE
    DM.Qry_Usb.SQL.Clear;
    DM.Qry_USB.SQL.Add( 'Select * from Cabezal' );
    DM.Qry_USB.SQL.Add( 'order by Fecha, Pedido' );
    DM.Qry_USB.Open;

    while not DM.Qry_USB.Eof do
    begin

        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Clear;    // MYSQL DB
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( 'Insert Into Cabezal ' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( '( Correla, Fecha, Hora, Cliente, Pedido, Direccion, ');
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( 'Entre, yEntre, Estado, Total, PedidoxWeb ) ' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( 'Values ( ' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( IntToStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('Correla').AsInteger ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( QuotedStr( FormatDateTime( 'DD.MM.YYYY', DM.Qry_Usb.FieldByName('Fecha').AsDateTime ) ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( QuotedStr( FormatDateTime( 'HH:MM:SS', DM.Qry_Usb.FieldByName('Hora').AsDateTime ) ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( IntToStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('Cliente').AsInteger ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( IntToStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('Pedido').AsInteger ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( QuotedStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('Direccion').AsString ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( QuotedStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('Entre').AsString ) + ',' );
        DM.FDQuery.SQL.Add( QuotedStr( DM.Qry_USB.FieldByName('YEntre').AsString ) + ')' );
        DM.FDQuery.ExecSQL;

        DM.Qry_USB.Next;

    end;
    DM.FDConnection.Commit;
```

I'm modifying the code to use parameters but still cant test it.

What else can I change to make this code faster ??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regads.

Comment: Use `TFDBatchMove`. Your code has at least these two flaws, iterating dataset through cursor, and repetitive command preparation (you could iterate underlying source data storage and for target prepare the command once and change only parameters). Still, `TFDBatchMove` is component just for this purpose.

Comment: What @Victoria says.  If you must do it with your loop for whatever reason. don't do all those `FieldByName` calls for each record in Qry_USB - look them up and assign them  to local Field vars before the loop starts.  And commit your destination transaction every few dozen rows.

Comment: And stop clearing the SQL between rows. Use parameters, set up the SQL once before the loop, and then just set the parameter values and execute the SQL inside the loop. This lets the server optimize it by setting up (identifying the parameters, creating placeholders for them) and compiling the SQL once and then cache that compiled statement. Saying *I'm modifying to use parameters but still cant test it* makes no sense. You modify it as I've indicated and then execute the code, and when it's done you're finished.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for your answers. I will try what you've mentioned and then let you know.

Comment: There's not much to analyze. Forget your code, what we said, and learn how to use `TFDBatchMove`. It will internally use DML array technique which should be the fastest possible way to move data from one DBMS to another. It's flexible enough to satisfy your task as well. @Ken, DML array insertion can improve this task quite much as well (for MySQL it's native). It would be reinventing a wheel in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Example resolving similar problem.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FireDAC.TFDQuery.Batch_Sample

```
  FDQuery1.SQL.add('sELECT * from cars');
  FDQuery1.open;


  FmMain.FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
  FDQuery2.sql.clear;
  FDQuery2.sql.add('INSERT INTO tributosasociados (id,NroContrib, CodTributo, CodImponible,descripcion,BAseImponible,Alicuota,FechaAlta,activo )');
  FDQuery2.sql.Add('VALUES(null, :NroContrib,:CodTributo,:CodImponible, :descripcion, :BAseImponible,:Alicuota,:FechaAlta,:activo)');


  FDQuery2.Params.ArraySize := FDQuery1.RecordCount;
   i := 0;
  while not FDQuery1.eof do
   begin
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('CodTributo').AsIntegers[i] := 3;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('NroContrib').AsIntegers[i] := FDQuery1.FieldByName('NroContrib').AsInteger;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('CodImponible').AsStrings[i] := FDQuery1.FieldByName('dominio').AsString;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('descripcion').AsStrings[i] := FDQuery1.FieldByName('descripcion').AsString +' / '+ FDQuery1.FieldByName('anio').AsString;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('BAseImponible').AsFloats[i] := FDQuery1.FieldByName('valuacion').AsFloat;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('Alicuota').AsFloats[i] := 1.7; // FDQuery1.FieldByName('****Ver Alicuta BUTA****').AsFloat;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('FechaAlta').AsdateTimes[i] := FDQuery1.FieldByName('FechaAlta').AsdateTime;
     FDQuery2.ParamByName('activo').AsIntegers[i] := 1;

     FDQuery1.next;
     i := i+1;
   end;

  FDQuery2.Execute(FDQuery2.Params.ArraySize);

  FmMain.FDConnection1.Commit;

 FDQuery1.close;
 FDQuery2.close;
 ShowMessage( intToStr(i) );
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer and how this solves the question being asked?